# DbTransaction.Commit Rollback, causing disruptions in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

So I have a complicated set of code (written by someone else), that has a function that conducts a number of database operations before finally Commit()ing the changes.

Here's the problem though, there are sub-functions in the code, that get called such as getThis or getThat, that have execute() and queryDatabase() functions. The code kept causing errors in some cases (not all cases), where it would freeze at this "execute" or "queryDatabase". Essentially, I think it's related to the fact that the code requires data from these queryDatabase commands before the changes are committed.

After deleting the passing of the dataAccess pointer to these sub functions, (thus they are not part of the commit), suddenly the code passes through successfully.

What is the proper way to use Commit() or should I just get rid of it and not use these transaction functions? Just let the code do everything instantly?

I can't even find the last error, just another vague "connection parameter null" SystemArgumentNullException that is somehow connected to it being a transaction.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null
Parameter name: connection
at Data.Database.PrepareCommand(DbCommand command, DbConnection connection)
```

It's hard to post code because it spans at least 20 different files (yeah, the original developer does not know KISS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Transaction.Connection will be set to null after the transaction is committed, which could be the reason why the connection is set to null if the code is passing around the Transaction.Connection as a reference to all the subfunctions.  The transaction doesn't own the connection, so it shouldn't be passed around to other subfunctions.

It sounds like the connection is being passed around all over the place.  A better way would be to place the connection in a `using` block and only place the commands that need that connection and assoicated transaction with it in tht `using` block.

Here's a basic pattern:

```
using(DbConnection connection = ...)

{

    connection.Open();

    using(DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(...))

    {

        ... do stuff ...

        transaction.Commit();        

    } // transaction rolled back here if an Exception is thrown before the call to Commit()

} // connection closed here
```

Transactions are necessary if the code is saving to multiple tables/records.  The unit of work needs to commit as a whole and not partially.  One way to get rid of the transactions is to have database manage them directly via a stored procedure.  The `BEGIN TRAN` is done explicitly in the stored procedure, at that point the C# code is no longer managing it.

Also take a look at the `System.Transactions` namespace.   I think it is easier to use than managing transactions on the connection itself.

Comment: I already do this:    if (_transaction != null)
        {
          _transaction.Commit();
        }

        _transaction = null;        ---- my feeling is that transactions are just buggy in this system. Because it keeps giving errors on every single queryDatabase or execute(). It just doesnt work well with transactions. Or maybe some sort of bug with Database class being passed in to sub functions, it's simply not working.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like more of a system/design issue.  For the queries into the database, they can be opened on a separate connection without the transaction if needed.  It sounds like its messy in there.

Comment: You would not believe how messy. But I'd be happier if ASP.nET didn't give out the worst errors in the planet: "DataAccessException: System.Data.DataSet queryDatabase(System.String, net.cadat.dataManager.dbConn.StoredProcedureParameter[]) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  ----- who knows where the error is. It's pointing the error to the db class file (can't know where that's coming from). All the DataAccess's are passed to sub functions as copies of them (no pass by reference), so somehow copying it to the other functions is causing errors.

Comment: Basically I had to remove passing by value of the DataAccess class I have, that contains the "Database" class. Just make a new DataAccess() in each function, otherwise, it continues to crash on every function because somehow this "connection" parameter gets lost when you pass by value I guess? I don't know how, basically it is voodoo, where database connections disappear when they desire (or a lack of documentation or trickery by microsoft where perhaps connections are deleted from the heap).

Answer (score 1):

After DbTransaction.Commit()/Rollback() transaction object goes into "zombie" state.
If you plan to continue using some commands outside of the transaction scope they must be detached from the transaction by setting Transaction property to null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, as I said, there is a beginTransaction(), then some queryDatabase() execute() and then commit(). It fails on each and every queryDatabase and execute, before it gets to commit. If I create a new dataAccess pointer inside the other functions, then they pass fine. In other words, transactions are super buggy in ASP.NET (or something is unexplained, like maybe you can't call any queries inside transactions--then whats the point of transactions?).

Answer (score 1):

A transaction should generally be used for a set of operations that logically represent a single unit of work.  In other words, if there are three actions performed in a transaction, and one of the actions fails or Rollback is called, the outcome should reflect that *none* of the three actions actually took place in the database.

So before you decide to remove the transaction, you will need to determine the intent of the original developer and the code (which may not be easy!).  If the actions need to succeeed or fail together, you will need to continue using the transaction.  If each action can succeed or fail on its own, you can likely get rid of the transaction altogether, as most database have implicit transactions for single calls.

Couple of rules of thumb: 1. transactions are expensive--start them as late as possible and commit them as early as possible; 2. it's often (not always) unnecessary to have reads/queries fall inside a transaction that includes writes.

[Database Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)

Comment: I know transactions are helpful. However, in this case they are causing impossible to fix errors, with vague descriptions of 'null connection'. Further, it's blatantly obvious the transactions themselves are causing the problem since the error occurs on database calls (even though the database and connections work fine). It's hard to determine whether it is important to have transactions here, I honestly don't mind any empty 'ghost data' in case of errors, but it is not good practice.

Comment: The bottom line is that transactions are either needed or they aren't for the operations in question.  Your team is going to need to either decipher the code and make transaction usage correct, or remove the transactions and take the risks associated with doing so.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to use Commit() or should I just get rid of it and not use these transaction functions? Just let the code do everything instantly?

Don't get rid of transactions. They make sense are exactly designed to keep your data consistent.

Comment: but it's causing me errors all over the code, and I can't fix them. The code is giving ridiculous errors, I think it's a systemic problem with ASP.nET to not give descriptive errors, debugging doesn't work, and trying to find errors with logs is taking forever. I can't keep track anymore. It's broken. ASP.NET doesn't handle transactions properly, if it did, there wouldn't be random errors that make no sense (that only happen when dataAccess is passed in; if a new dataAccess is created, then no errors, because transactions are buggy).